# Python, list of lists with sorted numbers by 4 first digits

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list which contains numbers and I want to create a new list which contains separate lists of all numbers with the same 4 first digits.

Example: make l2 from l1

```
l1 = [100023,100069,222236,22258,41415258,41413265,1214568...]

l2 = [[100023,100069],[222236,22258],[41415258,41413265],[1214568]...]
```

how can I create l2 from l1?

I tried iterating over the elements of l1 but w/o success!!

```
def main():

    l1=[100023,100069,222236,22258,41415258,41413265,1214568]
    l2=[[100023,100069],[222236,22258],[41415258,41413265],[1214568]]
    x=0
    n=1
    for i in l2:
        if i[0:4] == l2[n][0:4]:
            l2[x].append(i)
        else:
            l2[x+1].append(i)
    print(l2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Still not know how to proceed..

Comment: This code iterates over l2.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a dict as intermediate result and then convert this dict back to a list.
You also need to convert your integers to strings first.

```
l1 = [100023,100069,222236,22258,41415258,41413265,1214568]
l2 = []
l2dict = {}
for i in l1:
    prefix = str(i)[0:4]
    if prefix in l2dict.keys():
        l2dict[prefix].append(i)
    else:
        l2dict[prefix] = [i]
for item in l2dict.values():
    l2.append(item)
print(l2)
```

Comment: Disclaimer: This is a naive solution and is in no way optimized for large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) after converting the list elements to strings and using the first for digits as keys:

```
import itertools
l2 = [list(value) for key, value
      in itertools.groupby(l1, lambda x: str(x)[:4])]
print(l2)
```

EDIT: [Frieder's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51444325/8316315) is pretty much how this is implemented behind the scenes.

Comment: Very nice solution, although harder to understand for a beginner. I would rather upvote this, than my solution.